# How to encode string in utf-8 in C# if I am fetching Environment.Username which is non ascii

Tags: c#, windows, encoding, utf-8

```
using System;

namespace GetUsernameExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string username = Environment.UserName; //нпп
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + username); 
        }
    }
}
```

In this sample code, I want to get username which is non ascii string but I am getting output as "???"

I tried `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` and enabling "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"; then I get the correct non ascii output but I don't want to do the above (as I want to try out in application code not from console app, how can I encode in utf-8 and get the non ascii output).

Comment: "but i dont want to do the above" - if your console isn't set to an appropriate encoding, then you're not going to be able to get it to display everything. It's like saying "I want to watch films in colour, but I've only got a black and white TV, and I don't want to change that."

Comment: I mean its in the application not in the console, so in the application code i want to append non ascii string to some string but when i did debug it converting to "??"@JonSkeet

Comment: @Yaswanth the *application* will have no problem with non-ASCII characters; so: how are you trying to debug it? the `Console` is going to have a hard time here (although that will also depend a lot on which console you're using), but *that is just the display*; if you are using the *debugger*, the value should be correct; so: if you use the *debugger* (not the console), what does `username` display? For reference, if I do `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;` `Console.WriteLine("I'm  not  ASCII");` - it works fine: so... what are you doing differently and what are your reasons?

Comment: (but as I say: the handling of this output will be dependent on the console you're using; if you're using an OS or console that doesn't expect this: bad things)

Comment: private static String SendCommand(String username, int inst, String cmd)
        {
            try
            {
                string strCommandResponse = string.Empty;
                username = username.Trim();
                string pipename = "\\\\.\\pipe\\sample" + username; # this is my application code and pipe name is changing to "\\\\.\\pipe\\sample???" @MarcGravell , username is fetching the value of USERNAME env variable

Comment: Or it's just better to enable "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" In windows which solve the issue ( without code change)? @MarcGravell

Comment: @Yaswanth the comment in the code suggests that `username` is `"нпп"` - a perfectly reasonable UTF-16 string; I do not for one moment believe that `string pipename = "\\\\.\\pipe\\sample" + username;` is evaluating to `"\\\\.\\pipe\\sample???"` - so: *either* `username` is not in fact `"нпп"`, or you're writing `pipename` to the console; that's just a display problem - it doesn't say anything about what the value actually was. So once again; in the *debugger*, what was `pipename`? however: UTF-8 is irrelevant here; `string` happens to be UTF-16, but the details are an abstraction

Comment: If we assume that `pipename` is being passed to some API such as `NamedPipeClientStream` or something similar, the handling of the `string` to whatever encoding is used by the OS `extern` call: is an internal detail - I'm guessing it *won't* be UTF-8, but: making the *console* work (or not work) will do absolutely nothing relevant to making the pipe actually work (or not work)

Comment: @MarcGravell so u saying assuming pipename has no issue, but CallNamedPipe API handling pipename(which contains non ascii) has issue with non ascii pipenames?

Comment: @Yaswanth since you *still* haven't answered any of my questions: I'm not saying anything so absolute; I'm saying you need to separate the two things conceptually - console IO will have no impact on named pipes, and you'll need to use the debugger (and not the console) to reliably investigate where the failure lies